Unable to use OFFSET, FETCH NEXT with FOR UPDATE in ORACLE
I have a message table in ORACLE with the following structure ,
CREATE TABLE messages (
  ID varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  MESSAGE varchar(4000),
  STATUS varchar(20),
  CREATED_TIME date,
  LAST_UPDATED_TIME date
);

My use-case is to

read N number of records from the table whose status is NEW,
order by the created date
I should be able to skip M number of rows
since the data can be read from multiple clients to prevent the same data being returned to different clients I want to lock the selected rows.
If the length of message string is 0 then the message is ignored and the query is triggered in loop till N message are selected.
Once N non-zero length messages have been selected their status is marked as 'READ'.

I came up with the following query,
select * 
from messages 
where status = 'NEW' 
order by created_time 
offset M rows fetch next N rows only for update skip locked;

Following shows the code in java,
String sql = "select * from messages  where status = 'NEW' order by created_time  offset ? rows fetch next ? rows only for update skip locked";
int count = 0;
int offset = 0;
List<String> processedId = new ArrayList<>();
while(count < desiredCount){
try(Connection con = dataSource.getConnection;
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)){
    ps.setInt(1, offset);
    ps.setInt(2, desiredCount);
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
      while (rs.next()) {
       if(rs.getString("message").length > 0){
          count++;
          processedList.add(rs.getInt("id"));
          if(count == desiredCount) break;
       }
      }
    }
offset += desiredCount;    // increment offset to the amount of records read
    // logic to iterate over the processedList and mark the status to READ in DB against those ids
}

but this results in the following error
SQL Error [2014] [42000]: ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.

removing the offset and fetch next clause fixes the error but I need those to ensure I have correct number of records and when it is not possible to fetch desired record in the first iteration, the second iteration does not fetch the same rows again.
Can someone please offer a solution to the problem.

Is the messages really a table or a view? As the error message suggests that you are acting on a view. If it is, check the view definition for distinct or group by.

@MartinSchapendonk The in-line view is created by applying the FETCH clause (which is covered by the "etc." in the error message).

It is a table not a view. However, as per the comment from @MT0 the view is created implicitly. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Example fiddle

Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with an example of what you are trying to do following the FOR UPDATE clause because the solution is going to depend on what you are trying to achieve.

@MT0, updated the question to give more details on the requirement.

Don't go back and forth between Oracle and Java. Do the UPDATE in a single statement in Oracle (including checking that the message is not NULL, since an empty-string and NULL are identical in Oracle) and then return the final values to Java.
DECLARE
  v_ids SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  UPDATE messages
  SET status = 'READ',
      last_updated_time = SYSDATE
  WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT ROWID
    FROM   messages
    WHERE  status = 'NEW'
    AND    message IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY created_time
    OFFSET :1 ROWS FETCH NEXT :2 ROWS ONLY
  )
  RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids;

  OPEN :3 FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   messages m
           INNER JOIN TABLE(v_ids) r
           ON m.id = r.COLUMN_VALUE;
END;
/


Yep, this pretty much does it.
